# Output Tracing of Function Parameter Passing

Tags: c++, c

Output Tracing of C++ program.

How the parameter value is passing in function argument I cann't understand?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

void call(int,int,int,int);
int main(){
  int a=10;
  call(a,a++,++a,a);
  return 0;
}
void call(int x,int y,int z,int p){
  printf("%d %d %d %d",x,y,z,p);
}
```

Output:12 11 12 12
But cann't understand the logic behind this.

Answer (score 0):

`++val` will increase the value **before** doing the comparison.
`val++` will increase the value **after** the comparison succeeds.
**Code**

```
Arg1 = a
Arg2 = a
a += 1
a += 1
Arg3 = a
Arg4 = a
```

Comment: I also know that but how the fourth parameter that is passed as 10 becomes 12?

Comment: Well it's initialized as 10 and looking through my outline above you can see why. It's incremented twice (once via ++n and once via n++).

Comment: How about the others?

Comment: Well output 1 should be 10, all the others are as expected.